# Show two lines chart in R

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, linechart

this is my code in R:

```
datos_tem <- dbGetQuery(connection, paste("SELECT temp_int,hum_int,datetime FROM data WHERE host_id=69 and datetime>='2013-10-01' and datetime<='2013-10-03';", sep=""))
dbDisconnect(connection)

datos_tem$datetime <- as.date(datos_tem$datetime)
datos_tem$temp_int <- as.numeric(datos_tem$temp_int)
datos_tem$hum_int <- as.numeric(datos_tem$hum_int)

Molten <- melt(datos_tem, id.vars = "datetime")
print(Molten)
ggplot(Molten, aes(x = datetime, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
```

In database `temp_int,hum_int` is `Float`, and `datetime` is a `Datetime`.

When i run this, do not display the lines, only draw axis, legend,... , but if `print (Molten)` I have data melted fine :

[image]

Comment: `Datetime` is not a data type in R.  Currently, it looks like it is a `factor`.  take a look at `str(datos_tem)`.  Look at `?factor` for information on converting it and then also at `as.POSIXct` or its ilk for creating your time stamps.

Comment: When importing from a db, always check that what you think is a date is actually a date. It's probably either a factor or a character. You may need to coerce it to a date yourself in R.

Comment: Using POSIXct, looks it works!